# OpenCV 3+ version naming on Bionic

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to understand the versioning conventions of OpenCV on Ubuntu Bionic.  I'm interested in OpenCV 3+, and can build it myself if necessary, but I'd like to understand the rationale behind the versioning scheme of OpenCV that ships on the bionic repositories.

For example, I have some opencv libraries installed:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libopencv

ii  libopencv-calib3d-dev:amd64            3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-calib3d3.2
ii  libopencv-calib3d3.2:amd64             3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision Camera Calibration library
ii  libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64            3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-contrib3.2
ii  libopencv-contrib3.2:amd64             3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision contrlib library
ii  libopencv-core-dev:amd64               3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-core3.2
ii  libopencv-core3.2:amd64                3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision core library
ii  libopencv-dev                          3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for opencv
ii  libopencv-features2d-dev:amd64         3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-features2d3.2
ii  libopencv-features2d3.2:amd64          3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
ii  libopencv-flann-dev:amd64              3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-flann3.2
ii  libopencv-flann3.2:amd64               3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
ii  libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64            3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-highgui3.2
ii  libopencv-highgui3.2:amd64             3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
ii  libopencv-imgcodecs-dev:amd64          3.2.0+dfsg-4build2                  amd64        development files for libopencv-imgcodecs3.2
...
```

The versions of these libs are all "3.2".  However, when I dive into one of the individual packages:

```
$ dpkg-query -L libopencv-highgui-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/opencv2
/usr/include/opencv2/highgui
/usr/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp
/usr/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
/usr/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/share/doc/libopencv-highgui-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

It's clear here from the include directories that the opencv version is actually "opencv2".  So what gives?  Is "3.2" not actually the version of opencv, but the version of the ubuntu package?

Comment: IIRC the "2" in `opencv2` refers to the version of the OpenCV API - see for example [What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces)

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver, you are correct.  The OpenCV version is indeed 3.2